# Insulation exposed behind face of my fireplace

Tags: repair, insulation, fireplace

I recently had my house inspected and this was identified. I don't know if the previous owners used this fireplace regularly but it looks like the insulation between the face of the fireplace is exposed to the fire pit of my fireplace. What sort of suggestions should I take to cover this up?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that there is a piece of black metal trim lying in the basement, garage, or at the back of a closet shelf somewhere. It very much looks like there's a hole at the bottom, right next to the brick for it to screw or press into.

Comment: I'm not sure what that insulation does. What's on the other side? Is there a full steel liner against the brick? A wider photo showing the area below would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the original, it looks like you could make a new trim piece out of sheet metal pretty easily.

Comment: "pretty easily" is a relative term, but I agree with you on general principle

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, thanks for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.